# When can correlation be considered to predict direct or indirect relationship in the future?

Tags: statistics, correlation

If there's strong positive correlation between two variables X and Y, is it fine to conclude that increasing one (X) will lead to increase in the other (Y)?

I found some humorous examples that show that correlation does not imply causation [here](https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations). Let's consider this one:
[image]

Does this mean if many couples decide to marry in Kentucky then the number of people who drown will also increase?

What about a sensible example like "Correlation between positive news and stock prices"? Suppose the correlation is again 95.24%. If the amount of positive news increases, will it be okay to conclude that the stock prices will increase too? If yes in this case, then how exactly does one distinguish between this example and the one above?

Comment: Whether or not the correlation continues to hold into the future depends on the true relationship between the variables. If there is truly some underlying relationship between the two variables then they may continue to be correlated; however if the relationship is spurious or if one of the variables becomes impacted by some external force, the correlation may break down later.

Comment: If the reality is that both fishing boat deaths and Kentucky marriages are likely to fall over time, then they will continue to seem correlated into the future.  But if either reverses trend, there is no particular reason to expect the other also to reverse trend.